# Associative Array concat value to another associative array

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

What I have here is a delete multiple file function in codeigniter.  I need to merge or concat the value only of associative array. The value of both array was the file name and file extension of an image/file. I used md5 to change the name of the file.

This is my code

```
public function delete_files(){
    $filesCount = count($_FILES['file_certificate']['name']); 
    $file_certificate = [];
    $y = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++){
        $_FILES['file_certificates']['name']     = $_FILES['file_certificate']['name'][$i]; 
        $_FILES['file_certificates']['type']     = $_FILES['file_certificate']['type'][$i]; 
        $_FILES['file_certificates']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['file_certificate']['tmp_name'][$i]; 
        $_FILES['file_certificates']['error']     = $_FILES['file_certificate']['error'][$i]; 
        $_FILES['file_certificates']['size']     = $_FILES['file_certificate']['size'][$i]; 

        $oldname = $_FILES["file_certificates"]['name'];
        $file_ext[] = pathinfo($oldname,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $file_ray[] = trim(strtolower(md5(time().$oldname)));
        $result = array_combine($file_ray, $file_ext);
    }

        $path = FCPATH . 'uploads/certificate/';
        array_map('unlink', $result);
}
```

Here's my array right now

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGvr7.png)

I need it like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 46eced0ea722a94160d53b4abbb10381.jpg
    [1] => 4f9ca54fa1daa022dc31b991a673cab7.pdf
)
```

And also I never try this if its works deleting a multiple file via this code

```
$path = FCPATH . 'uploads/certificate/'; //path file location
array_map('unlink', $result);
```

Thank you.

Comment: `$result[] = trim(strtolower(md5(time().$oldname))) . '.' . pathinfo($oldname,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` …?

Answer (score 0):

I got this done using foreach.

```
$path = FCPATH . 'uploads/certificate/';
$data = array();
    foreach( $file_ray as $index => $code ) {
       $value = $path.$code.'.'.$file_ext[$index];
       $data[] = $value;
    }
```